# ASP.NET Core / SignalR: BackgroundService: eventhandler

Tags: .net-core, events

I have a tcpclient that runs and publishes an event when data is available. I'm trying to write a background service that reads this message and send it to a SignalR hub. I can't seem to figure out how to read the data that's published by the tcp client.

This is my code:

TcpManager.cs:

```
public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs<EventMessage>> DataEvent;

public async Task StartStreaming()
{
      string _ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
      int _port = 5543;

      _liveDataStreamer = new LiveDataDevice<EventMessage>(IPAddress.Parse(_ipAddress), _port); // awrapper around a TcpClient
      _liveDataStreamer.BytesReceivedEvent += _liveDataStreamer_BytesReceivedEvent;                        

      _liveDataStreamer.Start();
}

private void _liveDataStreamer_BytesReceivedEvent(object sender, BytesReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with read bytes
    var eventMessage = new EventMessage($"{_callerName}", $"{readBytesToASCII}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    try 
    { 
        this.OnDataEvent(new DataEventArgs<EventMessage>(eventMessage)); 
    } 
    catch { }
}

protected virtual void OnDataEvent(DataEventArgs<EventMessage> oargs)
{
    EventHandler<DataEventArgs<EventMessage>> _EventHandler = this.DataEvent;

    if (_EventHandler != null) 
    {
        _EventHandler(this, oargs); 
    }
}
```

My background service.cs:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    _tcpManager = TcpManager();
    await _tcpManager.StartStreaming();
     //how do I subscribe to the EventMessage that the tcpmanager notifies?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated TcpManager.cs to pass the callback function:

```
_liveDataStreamer.BytesReceivedEvent += (sender, e) => _liveDataStreamer_BytesReceivedEvent(sender, e, func);

private void _liveDataStreamer_BytesReceivedEvent(object sender, BytesReceivedEventArgs e, Func<EventMessage, Task> onMessageCallback){...onMessageCallback(eventMessage); }
```